# Why is the background image in my CSS file not being applied to my webpage?

Tags: html, css, background-image

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style sheets/style1.css" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Colorado National Parks and Monuments</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>Colorado National Parks and Monuments</h1>
    <br/>
    <h2><img src="images/Colorado Parks.gif" alt="Button to Colorado Parks webpage"/></h2>
    <h2><img src="images/Colorado Monuments.gif" alt="Button to Colorado Monuments webpage" usemap="#goToColMons"/></h2>
    <h2><img src="images/Spotlight Park.gif" alt="Button to Spotlight Park webpage"/></h2>
    <h2><img src="images/Places to Stay.gif" alt="Button to places to Stay webpage"/></h2>

    <map name="goToColMons">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,139,40" href="colorado_monuments.html"/>
    </map>

    <p>Colorado offers unequaled natural mountain scenery, abundant wildlife,</p>
    <p>and more outdoor activities than you can imagine. The name Colorado</p>
    <p>comes from the Spanish word “colorado” which means “reddish</p>
    <p>color.” On August 1, 1876, President Ulysses Grant proclaimed</p>
    <p>Colorado the 38th state.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

**style1.css**

```
body {
background-image: url('images/backg.jpg');
}

h1{
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: brown;
}
```

**The location of index.html is in the same folder as the folders images & style sheets.**

**The location of the image backg.jpg is in the images folder.**

**The location of style1.css is in the style sheets folder.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
background-image: url('../images/backg.jpg');
}
```

I think the path was wrong, you have to go one up.

Answer (score 1):

The path in your CSS file is relative to that file so your url should look like this...

```
body {
background-image: url('../images/backg.jpg');
}
```